# How to display html taken from xml file to page properly in Asp.Net Core 3

Tags: c#, html, xml, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.0

I am moving our FAQ's to an xml file in azure storage since they rarely change I don't want to hit the db for them each time.

My structure is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Faqs>
  <Faq question="Welcome to our updated FAQ!" number="0" category="welcome" > 
    <Answer>       
      <p> We have updated a lot of the content on our site, including this new FAQ page. We cannot possibly think of every question you night have so please feel free to ask us to put your questions and the answers on this page.
     You can do so by clicking the link below and sending us a contact form with your question(s)
     </p>                                     
    </Answer>
    <ImageUrl value=""/>
 </Faq>
 <Faq question="What benefits does the product provide?" number="1" category="product-information" > 
   <Answer>      
    <p> A decrease in fuel consumption, substantial improvement of DPF's and an overall increase in fuel burn efficiency translate to substantial emission reductions as well. The emission benefits are achieved due to a
        <ul>
          <li>More Complete Combustion</li>
          <li>Lower Operating Temperature</li>
          <li>Lower Overall Engine Pressure</li>
       </ul>

    These factors account for the <strong>reduction of unburned</strong> carbon being released during the exhaust stroke of the engine and/or back into the oil as soot.
     </p>
    <div>
      <img alt="2strokediesel" src="~/images/2strokediesel.png" />
      <span class="image-caption">2-stroke diesel engine with the product catalytic coating area shown (orange shading)</span>
    </div>      
  </Answer>
  <ImageUrl value=""/>
</Faq>
 ...rest removed
```

I thought I would store the entire html instead of just the text for ease of retrieval and creating the page but my code is not displaying the html as its stored in the xml file.

Either that is not doable (rarely the case) or there is some way of encoding/decoding the value returned so it displays properly.

Any help appreciated.

here is the razor for a section of the page

```
 <!-- Product Information -->
        <h2 class="h3 font-w600 push-30-t push">@ti.ToTitleCase(Model.ProductInformationFaqs[0].Category)</h2>
        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.ProductInformationFaqs.Count; i++)
        {
            var identifier = $"#faq1_q{i + 1}";

            <div id="faq1" class="panel-group">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title">
                            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"
                               data-parent="#faq1"
                               href="@identifier">@Model.ProductInformationFaqs[i].Question</a>
                        </h3>
                    </div>
                    @if (i == 0)
                    {
                        <div id="@identifier.Replace("#","")" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                @Html.Raw(Model.ProductInformationFaqs[i].Answer)
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <div id="@identifier.Replace("#","")" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                @Html.Raw(Model.ProductInformationFaqs[i].Answer)
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        }
        <!-- END Product Information -->
```

and for the sake of completeness

Here is the xml file retrieval code, in case I am supposed to be manipulating the retrieved value here first.

```
public List<FaqDto> GetFaqItems()
    {
        var query = _doc.Descendants("Faq")
            .Select(x => new FaqDto()
            {
                Category = x.Attribute("category")?.Value,
                Question = x.Attribute("question")?.Value,
                FaqNumber = Convert.ToInt16(x.Attribute("number")?.Value),
                Answer = x.Element("Answer")?.Value,
                ImageUrl = x.Element("ImageUrl")?.Attribute("value")?.Value
            }).ToList();

        return query;
    }
For example:
```

FAQ #1 in the xml should be showing an unordered list that looks like this

```html
 <p>
    A decrease in fuel consumption, substantial improvement of DPF's and an overall increase in fuel burn efficiency translate to substantial emission reductions as well. The emission benefits are achieved due to a
    <ul>
       <li>More Complete Combustion</li>
       <li>Lower Operating Temperature</li>
       <li>Lower Overall Engine Pressure</li>
    </ul>

    These factors accounts for the <strong>reduction of unburned</strong> carbon being released during the exhaust stroke of the engine and/or back into the oil as soot.      

 </p>
```

but it looks like this

[image: Displaying]

Comment: What do you mean by 'my code is not displaying the html as its stored in the xml file'? Can you show an example?

Comment: @RuardvanElburg...See the addition to the end of the post. Thanks for looking

Comment: My guess is that `x.Element("Answer")?.Value` returns text only. I don't know what library you are using, but something equivalent to InnerHtml may preserve the tags.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve html from an xml file element of attribute, it is best to wrap the html in a CDATA element. Your xml should look like this and then it will retrieve and display properly using Html.Raw(your string here) in an Asp.Net Razor or MVC application

Sample xml file

```
<Faqs>
  <Faq question="Welcome to our updated FAQ!" number="0" category="welcome" > 
  <Answer>  
    <![CDATA[<html>
  <p>We have updated a lot of the content on our site, including this new FAQ page. We cannot possibly think of every question you night have so please feel free to ask us to put your questions and the answers on this page. You can do so by clicking the button below and sending us a contact form with your question(s)  
  </p>
      </html>
   ]]>                                           
  </Answer>
  <ImageUrl value=""/>
  </Faq>
</Faqs>
```